# Index key size limit in MariaDB 10.1.x vs 10.2.x

Tags: mariadb

Our database backend business logic creates the following query:

```
CREATE INDEX TESTINDEX ON TESTTABLE (URI(1024));
```

In MariaDB 10.1.24, we get the following error:

```
Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes
```

On the other hand, for MariaDB 10.2.6, everything works correctly. I would like to undestand why this is. Within the MariaDB knowledge base, I found [this article](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/converting-tables-from-myisam-to-innodb/) which seems to describe the problem.

Does anybody know, if this is simply a configuration issue, or was there a code change which allows larger keys now?

I guess it could be due to the changed storage engine XtraDB=>InnoDB [(see here)](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/what-is-mariadb-102/#innodb-as-default).

Comment: And what is the output of  SHOW WARNINGS in 10.2 ?

Comment: @GeorgRichter: there are no warnings for 10.2 (I tested 10.2.6)

Comment: The limit for 10.2.6 is 3072 bytes